# open redirect via POST?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, url-redirection, url

HTTP Request(POST):

```
per_page=security.stackexchange.com&order=questions&redirect=HTTP://security.stackexchange.com/
```

So when I record my request I get these 3 parameters and when I edited it a little bit, then click forward(Burp Suite), then I get redirected to the given site (in this case I get redirected to security.stackexchange.com).

So my questions is: Is my site vulnerable to Open Redirect? and is it a serious security vulnerability?

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is paste that link into the browser and you're redirected to http://security.stackexchange.com then yes it is a vulnerability.

The seriousness of the vulnerability depends on the expectations of the site and how much a user trusts it. If I can send some person a link to your site that contains a redirect to my malicious site, and they think "oh, that's important I need to click it" then its fairly serious. That redirected link can take them pretty much anywhere, which could lead to phishing, malware, etc., all the while the user thinks they're being taken to your site.

Comment: But it's not in browser because its POST method and I must first record requests than edit parameters to get redirected ?

Comment: What happens if you take that URL verbatim and stick it in your browser so it does do a GET request? Does it take you to this site?

Comment: I tried but no, it just redirect me to own site. Maybe i don't know to convert from POST to GET

Comment: @rood why do you have to record the request first? All the parameters seem static, so that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @tim I have to, how can I change parameters values without it ? If I don't know to convert to GET(but i think it can't convert to GET because I get redirected to homepage) or I just don't have a much knowlegde about it.